# Creating a 1:1 NAT with iptables

Tags: iptables, raspberry-pi

I am trying to learn a bit about NAT translations in Linux, but I havent seen any proof-of-concept that was boiled down to as basic as possible.

Anyway. Here is a drawing of my setup:

[image: simple network with two subnets]

I have a very basic router to the Internet. It can basically only do 2 things:

- Make a connection to the internet.
- Handout ip address on 1 subnet alone.

It **cannot** do static routing at all.

... and it does not even know what a IPv6 address looks like! (No kidding!)

What I want is to be able to connect to the Internet from `Raspberry 3`, but also being able connect from `My Computer` to the `Raspberry 3` or any other device on the other subnet.

That gave me the idea to implement a 1:1 NAT on my `Raspberry 4`, where all ip adresses from the 192.168.10.x/24 range gets translated into 192.168.1.x/24 range.

That way it appears at least from my routers point of view that all hosts on the network belongs to the same subnet, since the address pool of 192.168.0.0/23 is from 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.1.255.

But how to go about it?

Is it enough to just add two rules to iptables on the raspberry 4 like:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.10.0/24 -j NETMAP --to 192.168.1.0/24
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j NETMAP --to 192.168.10.0/24
```

Or do I need to be a bit more explicit about the direction of ip packages?

**Update:**

In order to help with the troubleshooting I can inform that the Raspberry 4 acts as a DHCP server for both my subnets.

It advertises itself as the first hop, when doing a traceroute from any machine to the Internet - on either net.

A traceroute from `My computer` to lets say Google will show something like:

- 1: Raspberry 4
- 2: Primitive Router
- 3: ISP gateway
- 4: ...
- ...
- n: Google.com

However traceroute goes bad when done from my `Raspberry 3`.

First jump will be the `Raspberry 4`, so no surprice there, but the route wont give a reply on ping, as it does not know how to reach the 192.168.10.0/24 subnet.

For your information my `Raspberry 4` already acts a site-2-site VPN client, so if all other things fail, then I can just do sourced based routing and send all traffic via my VPN connection, though at a significant speed penalty (around 70% speed drop).

**Update 2:**

Output from the Raspberry 4:

```
# ip rule show

0:      from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

# ip route show table main

default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.0.136 metric 202
192.168.0.0/23 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.136 metric 202
192.168.100.0/24 dev tun-ipv6 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.10
```

- The router resides at 192.168.0.1.
- The subnet 192.168.100.0/24 is inside my VPN.

That part works fine as I have no intentions to send all traffic through my VPN.

It is trivial for me to create a new routing table to redirect from 192.168.10.0/24 via VPN as I have already done that particual trick one time before in order to use IPv6 on my local lan. :-)

However Tom Yan solution looks quite a bit what I was aiming for particularly his hint about "AnyIP". :-)

I need todo a bit of testing, but I will accept his answer. :-)

Comment: If memory serves - you should be setting up a route between the two routers should do. Unfortunately I don't actually recall how I did it. While its out of scope of the answer [This and other articles on ars technica are great starting points](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2016/04/the-ars-guide-to-building-a-linux-router-from-scratch/). I took [a slightly different approach  on my build](https://journeymangeek.com/?p=196)- but my [ipv6](https://journeymangeek.com/?p=228) tunnel setup should work with other guides too.

Comment: Yes routing works fine between the two local lan, when I assign an ip address on both interfaces. But that is because my DHCP server tells my net to use my raspberry 4 as the default gateway. However since the router has static ip and _is_ actual gateway towards the Internet, I cannot use this trick to send traffic from the Internet towards the raspberry. And as I said it cannot do static routing at all, so it does not know how to reach the 192.168.10.0/24 net. That makes NAT the final resort for my network.

Comment: Hmm, seems like you have only one NIC on the Pi 4. So how are the Pi 4 and Pi 3 connected to each other? I thought you already set up `192.168.10.0/24`.

Comment: I do have 2 NIC - the other NIC is attached through USB ... and I have a third that is virtual (tun-ipv6). However when I did the dump from `ip route` I had not attached the second NIC to my other switch, so it flagged `eth1` as being down.

Comment: I admit I don't fully understand what you're trying to achieve, but is it possible it would be easier for you to just use Wireguard and add all your nodes to it, say using the Pi4 as a "vpn server" and using normal home nat masquerading on it?

Comment: The goal was having a segmented LAN where both subnets had access to the Internet, but where I could restrict network address on one subnet. Imagine `Raspberry 3` is placed in a subnet designed for test. Currently I am working with IoT, so there are situations where you want restricted network access in order to not mess with rest of the network. Unfortunately the ISP provided router is basically just a modem with WiFi capabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the source NAT should be:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.10.0/24 -j NETMAP --to 192.168.1.0/24
```

(`POSTROUTING` with an `-s` match)

and the destination NAT should be:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j NETMAP --to 192.168.10.0/24
```

(`PREROUTING` with a `-d` match)

*Note: AFAIK the destination NAT rule is only needed for "NEW" traffic (from within the LAN). The source NAT rule is sufficient for return traffic, as destination NAT for any of those is "implied" by it.*

But then there's the problem: how will `My Computer` and `Primitive Router` know that traffic for `192.168.1.0/24` (which are"actually" `192.168.10.0/24`) should go to `Raspberry Pi 4` for further routing?

The answer is, you need `Raspberry Pi 4` to response to ARP requests for `192.168.1.0/24`.

One of the ways to achieve that is to set up something called "AnyIP" (at least that's term I heard of). Essentially that means adding a subnet route of type `local` for `192.168.1.0/24`:

```
ip r add local 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0
```

*Note: I don't exactly remember if this would work with the `arp_ignore` sysctl set to e.g. `1`.*

Make sure you enabled IP(v4) forwarding with sysctl and that no firewall on `Raspberry Pi 4` blocks forwarding traffic that you desire (as per a rule or the chain policy).

Comment: Well I did cheat a small bit, because the raspberry 4 is ALSO acting as a site-2-site VPN client, so I have already setup the network to use it as default gateway for the 192.168.0.0/23 net. I just figured adding ANOTHER interface should not make the whole thing harder,?

Comment: `as it does not know how to reach the 192.168.10.0/24 subnet` so what's the default route/gateway in the main table of `Raspberry Pi 4`? And have you already configured any ip rule that (unintentionally) route the traffics of `Raspberry Pi 3` into the VPN tunnel? The VPN thing is pretty much irrelevant to your original question, *as long as* it's *specific* enough to not interfere with the desired LAN setup. I have no idea why you suddenly talks about "route everything into the tunnel" while you were trying to "expose" an inner LAN to its outer LAN.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to learn a bit about NAT translations in Linux, but I havent seen any proof-of-concept that was boiled down to as basic as possible.

Here's my basic-as-possible script that I use on my desktop PC to "share internet" when I connect another device up to it via LAN:

```
#!/bin/bash

# masquerade $1 (e.g. eth0, ppp0) as $2 (default wlan0)

INTIF="$1"
EXTIF=${2:-wlan0}

echo $INTIF $EXTIF

echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F INPUT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F OUTPUT 
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -F FORWARD 
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -A FORWARD -i $EXTIF -o $INTIF -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i $INTIF -o $EXTIF -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $EXTIF -j MASQUERADE
```

You need to call it with the "internal" interface (the network with clients that need NAT) and the "external" interface (towards the internet). Setup of the internal interface, and DHCP etc. is not included (you were only asking about NAT).

> That gave me the idea to implement a 1:1 NAT on my Raspberry 4, where all ip adresses from the 192.168.10.x/24 range gets translated into 192.168.1.x/24 range.

That's a lot more difficult than "basic NAT".

But you don't have to do that, and in fact, it wouldn't work well with your primitive router / Raspberry Pi 4 combination. Instead, just do basic NAT on the Raspberry Pi 4. This will mean everything on 192.168.10.*/24 will NAT to 192.168.0.0, and the router will understand that just fine.

(And in real life, you'd just connect the two switches, and have a single subnet provided from your router. BTW, if your primitive router can be re-flashed with OpenWRT etc., it'll also be able to do, well, routing).

Comment: I'd wish my router could be flashed. However the router belongs to my ISP, so fat chance! The ONLY thing they have going for them is the can give me a 600 mbps connection through fiber, while the only alternative is VDSL @ 15 mbps on a good day. Subscription price is about the same between 600 mbps fiber and 15 mbps VDSL.

Answer (score 1):

No, adding the NAT rules is not enough. Because discovery of IPv4 hosts on the local network (broadcast segment) works using ARP. The broadcast traffic of ARP would not cross your inner NAT box and the NAT box would not respond either. To make it respond you need `proxy_arp`.

However, it is unclear what this kind of setup would achieve. Just put everything in one network or add routes to PCs (instead of the router) and MASQUERADE only to the outer router.